# Opening a JSON file in python

Tags: python, json

This is the first time I try to use a JSON file in Python and although I have read a lot of stuff regarding this matter, I am still very confused. I want to read a file named jason.json line by line, store it to a list named data and then print it. However, i always get the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "try.py", line 6, in <module>
    data.append(json.loads(line))
  File "C:\Users\...\Python35\lib\json\__init__.py", line 319, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\...\Python35\lib\json\__init__.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\...\Python35\lib\json\__init__.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
  json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 2 column 1 (char 2)
```

This is my code:

```
import json
data = []
with open('jason.json') as f:
    for line in f:
        data.append(json.loads(line))

print(data)
```

And this is jason.json:

```
{
  "E(2,3)" : "A common Afro-Cuban drum pattern",
  "E(2,5)" : "A rhythm found in Greece",
  "E(3,4)" : "It is the archetypal pattern of the Cumbia from Colombia",
  "E(3,5)" : "Persian rhythm"
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You need to load the whole file in one go; each individual line is **not** valid JSON.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters solution is the way to go. However, the reason you have this problem is that you probably created the file manually or copied that from else where such that it has line breaks. Normally .json files do not have line breaks, and therefore your only line would be valid json. You can save a data structure to a file with `json.dump(my_data, my_file)` it will no have line breaks, and you could (though not advised) load it using your approach.

Comment: @Akavall: no, JSON easily can have line breaks. Use `json.dump(my_data, my_file, indent=4)` for example. JSON was never designed to be treated as a single-line format, really.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I see. Thank you for the information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that the data stored in `jason.json` is a dict and not a list. So, if you want a list of tuples, you can do something like

```py
with open('jason.json') as f:
    data = list(json.load(f).items())
print(data)
```

which yields

```
[('E(3,5)', 'Persian rhythm'), ('E(3,4)', 'It is the archetypal pattern of the Cumbia from Colombia'), ('E(2,3)', 'A common Afro-Cuban drum pattern'), ('E(2,5)', 'A rhythm found in Greece')]
```

Comment: Thank you this really helped!

Answer (score 4):

You are reading your file line by line, but a single line from your file is not a valid JSON document:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads('{\n')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mjpieters/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 319, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Users/mjpieters/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/Users/mjpieters/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 2 column 1 (char 2)
```

Decode the **whole** file in one go; this is easiest done with the `json.load()` function:

```
with open('jason.json') as f:
    data.append(json.load(f))
```

Comment: I think it is data = json.load(f) data does not yet exist

Comment: @PyNEwbie: In the question, `data = []` is defined before the `with` statement. I've merely focused on the `with` block.

Comment: I also think he does not know what a json object is he seems to think adding the key,value pairs is what data should be

Comment: @PyNEwbie: that's just speculation; we have no evidence either way.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Oh I didn't know that.Thank you very much!